# Substring of a List<string>

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a `List<string>` with the following definition:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in tzctStgImpCheck.Rows)
 {
     Console.WriteLine();
     for (int x = 0; x < tzctStgImpCheck.Columns.Count; x++)
     {
         List<string> spon = new List<string> { };

         tableRow = row[x].ToString();

         spon.Add(tableRow);
     }
 }
```

Each table row would contain string like:

`##SP00000000007 12/31/2015 12:00:00 AM12/31/2014 12:00:00 AM##`

I want to store `SP00000000007` in one variable, `12/31/2015` is another variable and `12/31/2014` in another variable. How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like you would want to `Split` this string at several locations. Have you tried that?

Comment: During each iteration of your `for` loop, you *create a new, empty list `spon`*, *add one single entry to it* and then *throw it away*. I doubt that this is what you want.

Comment: @AlkeshDeshpande use the debugger and also inspect the items in your  `spon` object and you will see where are are making a mistake.. also where are you using substring..?

Comment: I believe we would also need to know how consistent the format is. With just the one example of a possible string it would be difficult to make a robust parsing routine.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the original string and use the String.CompareOrdinal Method (String, String) to test for the spaces that are present inside the original string. I believe the ordinal value for a (space) is the 32.

Then it's just a matter of your use of a loop to test each letter of the original string from beginning to end, concatenate the value into a variable as you go and dump the value of the variable into an array when you hit the spaces or the end of the string.

Just don't forget to increment your place in the array :-) , but you should end up with your substrings inside the array all nice and neat.

p.s. I haven't done this in C or C#, but I have done it in javascript and ruby. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    foreach(string item in listOfItems){
        string[] var = item.split(' ');
        string s1 = var[0].replace("#", "");
        string s2 = var[1];
        string s3 = var[3].replace("AM", "");
        //Do whatever you want with your parameters...
    }
```